# certificate validation failure from trustore having more than one public certificate with same Distinguished name?

Tags: java, netty, x509certificate

I have a scenario where the customer public certificate is going to get expired, so he created a new public certificate with the same DN. Upon validating the user certificates which are generated using the customer's certificate using the client certificate key.
so, when the trustore has both the public key, it only validates the one generates with older public key not with the new public key. for others it throws an error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkClientTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:264)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:700)
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:595)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1202)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1324)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:201)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1380)
```

Comment: I don't know netty but that stack suggests a combination of OpenSSL and Java crypto. If OpenSSL is doing the chain build, it definitely looks up parents and anchors by Subject DN, and if it has more than one cert with the same DN it may find the wrong one, especially without AKI/SKI. Real CAs never keep the exact name for a different key, AFAICT precisely to allow this behavior in reliers; they always tweak the name at least slightly like 'Verisign Root G4' instead of 'Verisign Root G3'. (Bearing in mind _all_ Verisigns are now tainted by Symantec and being phased out as rapidly as possible.)

Comment: thank you @dave_thompson_085 Do we have an option to handle the user certificate which was generated using the old customer CA file or we will have to regenerate using the new CA key file.

Comment: As I said, I don't know netty. Java does split the API into separate build and validate, so _if_ you can use that _and_ you can build the correct chain yourself, it might work, but I wouldn't rely on it without testing. That said, if you can change the CA name(s) to follow 'normal' practice I'd consider that more robust.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I was able to make it work by forming a proper chain construction while using AKI / SKI